# influxdb python get item in variable

Tags: python, resultset, influxdb

Heyya,

how do I get the value '47' from the output into a variable without all the whole frame?

```
client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
result = client.query(query)
result = list(result.get_points(measurement='moisture'))
print "--> %s" % result
```

results in

```
[{u'value': 47, u'time': u'2018-01-17T18:41:30.486209257Z'}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

ok, got It by myself

```
moisture = result.raw['series'][0]['values'][0][1]
print "moisture: %s" % moisture
```